# jQuery shows a li when clicking different li

Tags: jquery

**HTML**

```
<div class="testimony">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>WHAT PEOPLE SAY ABOUT ME</h1>
        <ul class="test-con">
            <li class="current">
                <a class="image-frame" href="">
                    <img src="images/testi-1-100x100.jpg">
                </a>
                <h5>“ Aenean nonummy hendrerit mau phasellu porta.... ”</h5>
                <h6>- Sam Owens</h6>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="image-frame" href="">
                    <img src="images/testi-1-100x100.jpg">
                </a>
                <h5>“ Aenean nonummy hendrerit mau phasellu porta.... ”</h5>
                <h6>- Matthews</h6>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="image-frame" href="">
                    <img src="images/testi-1-100x100.jpg">
                </a>
                <h5>“ Aenean nonummy hendrerit mau phasellu porta.... ”</h5>
                <h6>- Micheal</h6>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="navigator">
            <li class="current"></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$('.navigator li').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('current').siblings().removeClass('current');
    $(this).each(function(){
        $('.test-con li').each(function(){
            var first= $('.test-con li:first-child');
            $(first).closest('li').addClass('current').siblings().removeClass('current');
        });
    });
});
```

I am able to get the previous `li`. Could someone suggest a best result using `li` each function? Or some other function which gets me a perfect match? I would like to do it in `jQuery`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Format your code to look better.

Comment: what's the logic behind this.? `$(this).each(function(){`  :|

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="testimony">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>WHAT PEOPLE SAY ABOUT ME</h1>
        <ul class="test-con">
            <li class="current">
                <a class="image-frame" href="">
                    <img src="images/testi-1-100x100.jpg">
                </a>
                <h5>“  mau phasellu porta Aenean nonummy hendrerit.... ”</h5>
                <h6>- Sam Owens</h6>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="image-frame" href="">
                    <img src="images/testi-1-100x100.jpg">
                </a>
                <h5>“ Aenean nonummy hendrerit mau phasellu porta.... ”</h5>
                <h6>- Matthews</h6>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="image-frame" href="">
                    <img src="images/testi-1-100x100.jpg">
                </a>
                <h5>“ hendrerit mau phasellu  Aenean nonummy porta.... ”</h5>
                <h6>- Micheal</h6>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="navigator">
            <li class="current"></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
 </div>
$('.navigator li').click(function () {
        var index = $(this).index();
        $('.test-con li').hide();
    $('.test-con li').eq(index).addClass('current').fadeIn().siblings().removeClass('current');
    });

.test-con li{
    display:none;
}
.test-con li.current{
    display:inline-block;
}
.navigator li
{
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:10px;
    background-color:#000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating `$(this)` which is wrong because `$(this)` is single object and the list of object.

You can take index of clicked `li` and use same to show respective `li` inside `test-con`.

Use below jQuery and it is better to wrap it inside `$(function(){..});` :

```
$(function(){
    $('.navigator li').click(function(){
             var index = $(this).index();
            $(this).addClass('current').siblings().removeClass('current');
            $('.test-con li').removeClass('current');
            $('.test-con li:eq('+index+')').addClass('current');
        });
   });
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Yu7s8/4/)**

Comment: Hey thanks for ur results but it didn't work in case but the below code able to achieved my result.

Comment: '$('.navigator li').click(function () {
        var index = $(this).index();
        $('.test-con li').hide();
        $('.test-con li').eq(index).addClass('current').fadeIn().siblings().removeClass('current');
    });'

Comment: Sorry my bad, actually `function(index)` will not work for `.click` but for `.each()`.. I have updated my answer and added demo link. Rest of the code is ok, please see.